# QGLBuffer.allocate messes with QGLWidget.renderText

Tags: qt, opengl

When I call QGLBuffer.allocate QGLWidget.renderText stops working entirely. In fact all QPainter functionality stops working, event if you overload QGLwidget.paintEvent

The following PySide code demonstrates the issue. It will open two QGLwidget windows:

- one calls QGLBuffer.allocate and you can not see the text.
- The other works fine.

Code:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtOpenGL import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
import sys

class GLWidget(QGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, alloc=False):
        QGLWidget.__init__(self)
        self.alloc = alloc

    def initializeGL(self):
        self.buffer = buffer = QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer.VertexBuffer)
        buffer.create()
        buffer.bind()
        buffer.setUsagePattern(QGLBuffer.StaticDraw)

        if self.alloc: # If true text will not be drawn
            buffer.allocate(80)

    def resizeGL(self, h, w):
        glViewport(0, 0, h, w)

    def paintGL(self):

        glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        glColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
        self.renderText(50, 50, "Text to Render")

def main(argv):

    app = QApplication(argv)

    widget = GLWidget(alloc=True)
    widget.show()

    widget2 = GLWidget(alloc=False)
    widget2.show()

    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly how the Qt OpenGL classes work, but in my experience with mixing Qt and raw OpenGL 3.3 you should unbind when you are finished with a buffer because it messes with whatever mechanism QPainter is using.

So after at the end of initializeGL unbind, and bind/unbind in paintGL.

Comment: Thanks 'QGLBuffer.bind()' <-> 'QGLBuffer.release()'